# Unable tor receive parse push notifications when app is killed Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using parse sdk for android and testing my app in an Android lollipop 5.0. I can receive push notifications when app is running or in background, but when I kill it or close it I can't. Here is my manifest.xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ver.verapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.ver.verapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ver.verapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:name="com.ver.verapp.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="Z8Uof8cKL0FTs118iLUOOsjY4" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/verapp_push"/>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.ver.verapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my custom Application Code:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
private static String TAG_SESSIONTOKEN ="sessionToken";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "XXXX", "XXXX");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    String Token = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("verapp", 0);
    if(Token!=null)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("tokenParse", Token);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        Token="";
    }
}



@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, my Asus Zenfone 2 had a pre installed app named Start Manger that was preventing my app from waking up alone, i had to enable it and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Here:

**Create a new *class* called Service. In there, put this in the oncreate: **

```
 Parse.initialize(this, "XXXX", "XXXX");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Then, go to your manifest and add this:

```
<application
name:"pacakge.name.to.ServiceClass"
...
>
...
```